# Java attribute which implements a certain Interface

Tags: java, interface, attributes

Say I have a class which I want to add an attribute to. The value of this property should implement a certain interface. I do, however, not care at all what kind of object/class it is, as long as it implements the methods from a certain interface.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

In Objective-C, I would do it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <MyInterface> attr;
```

Comment: `<modifier> MyInterface attr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the field in your class as the type of the interface:

```
public class YourClass {
    private MyInterface attr;
}
```

It won't matter the class the object reference belongs to, it only matters if the class implements the desired interface. Here's an example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<String> stringList;
    public void setStringList(List<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }
}

//...
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setStringList(new ArrayList<String>());
myClass.setStringList(new LinkedList<String>());
```

From your comment:

> I don't think of Interfaces as types. More like a feature an object has.

In Java, an interface is a type. If you want some type to have declared two interfaces at the same time, you can create a third interface that extends from both:

```
interface ThirdPartyInterface1 {
}

interface ThirdPartyInterface2 {
}

interface MyInterface extends ThirdPartyInterface1, ThirdPartyInterface2 {
}

public class YourClass {
    private MyInterface attr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if it would have to implement multiple interfaces?

Comment: @Jenox Variables are declared with a single type.

Comment: @Jenox you can only use one interface. Make sure the other interfaces extend from a top level interface.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think of Interfaces as types. More like a feature an object has. And obviously it can have multiple. In Objective-C I would do `<Interface1, Interface>`. Are you telling me that this is not possible in Java?

Comment: @Jenox that may be for Objective C, but in Java interfaces are types.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Huh, that feels like a weird concept to me. What is the point of using an interface compared to an abstract superclass then?

Comment: @Jenox in Java, a class can only extend from a single class while it can implement one or several interfaces. I recommend you to start reading some Java tutorials.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Lol. I do understand these concepts, no need to read a tutorial. I was just wondering what the point was if you could only require an attribute to implement one interface. While your edit does clarify how one *could* do that, I still don't like the approach of Java here. I mean, say a third party class implements TPI1 and TPI2 and I require an attribute to implement these two. If I would create a 'wrapper interface' as you suggested, this would not work, I guess, because the third party class does not implement *my interface*, which *could* have added additional methods...

Comment: @Jenox that's how Java works. You may create a wrapper class that implements `MyInterface` and resolves the methods by composition of classes that implements methods from both interfaces.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Which is a total overkill for something as simple as wanting an attribute to obey to two interfaces. Anyway, thanks. I guess I simply won't ever get along with Java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am only saying that it is a lot of stuff to do for something very simple. No need to apologize.